# build CollapsingToolbar with an ImageView along with a custom layout at the bottom

Tags: java, android, xml, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-motionlayout

This is what I want to achieve, there will be a custom layout below the image in a CollapsingToolbar, the layout will contain a couple of view items. [1](https://ibin.co/4mY6hCv1DYAj.jpg)

The required behaviour is, upon scrolling, the bottom layout will gradually fade and disappear and the image on top will shrink in size and gets pinned up as a toolbar.

I have already built a CollapsingToolbar using just an image and it's working fine. Though I'm stuck at adding a custom layout at the bottom as said.

Do I need to skip CollapsingToolbar and use something else such as MotionLayout ??

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/sdv_add_iamge_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            app:overlayImage="@color/trans_black"
            android:tint="#11000000"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5"
            app:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"/>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.framelayout.title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.2"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_back"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/back"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <com.jude.easyrecyclerview.EasyRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:name="com.socialinfotech.feeedj.TimeLineActivities.ViewCompanyDetailsActivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:behavior_overlapTop="30dp"
            app:layout_progress="@layout/view_progrss"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="com.socialinfotech.feeedj.TimeLineActivities.ViewCompanyDetailsActivity"
            tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Instead of the CollapsingToolbarLayout, you can use the powerful [MotionLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/motion/MotionLayout) which is a subclass of ConstraintLayout for building animations. If you are happy to replace the existing view hierarchy with a flat MotionLayout equivalent, read the detailed answer given below.

---

Here I am going to show you how to create the collapsing header layout animation as per your requirement all with in three simple steps.

Before writing any code, see the gif image given below to better understand what we are trying to create.

[image: gif image showing sample animation]

**1. Add the ConstraintLayout dependency:**

To use MotionLayout in your project, add the ConstraintLayout 2.0 dependency to your app's build.gradle file. If you're using AndroidX, add the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
}
```

**2. Create the MotionLayout file:**

MotionLayout is a subclass of ConstraintLayout, so you can transform any existing ConstraintLayout into a MotionLayout. So create one layout file as shown below.

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    motion:layoutDescription="@xml/motionscene"
    tools:showPaths="true">


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
            android:text="@string/large_text" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/headerBg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/headerHeight"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/materialwallpaper"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/customHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/headerHeight"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#66FF2345"
            android:text="custom header item"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </FrameLayout>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/headerHeight"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:background="#345634"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material"
        android:tint="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Page Title"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/customHeader"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

**3. Create a MotionScene:**

In the previous step, app:layoutDescription attribute references a MotionScene. A MotionScene is an XML resource file that contains all of the motion descriptions for the corresponding layout. To keep layout information separate from motion descriptions, each MotionLayout references a separate MotionScene. Note that definitions in the MotionScene take precedence over any similar definitions in the MotionLayout.

Following is a sample MotionScene file that creates the required fixed/pinned toolbar with 'enterAlways' effect:

Put the file in the xml folder under the res directory.

*motionscene.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/collapsed"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/expanded">

        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:moveWhenScrollAtTop="true"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/scrollView"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="top" />

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/headerBg"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/headerHeight"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        </Constraint>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/customHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/headerHeight"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <PropertySet android:alpha="1" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/headerHeight"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <PropertySet android:alpha="0" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/customHeader"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="textSize"
                motion:customDimension="16sp" />

        </Constraint>


    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/collapsed">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/headerBg"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </Constraint>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/customHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <PropertySet android:alpha="0" />
        </Constraint>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <PropertySet android:alpha="1" />
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/home"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="textSize"
                motion:customDimension="10sp" />
        </Constraint>


    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

That's all. You created an amazing custom animation with out writing any java/kotlin code. MotionLayout is fully declarative, meaning that you can describe any transitions in XML, no matter how complex.

Comment: your code is woking fine when I manually sets text in andorid:text="SOME_TEXT" but when i set it using method setText() then it is showing normal text and does not animate.

Comment: The biggest to my mind is setting a custom `imageview` which acts as a `back button`. This custom backbutton has NOT the same margins as the default backbutton and does NOT scale up as the default backbutton.

Comment: @Darish what is the value of headerHeight